# drush sql-dump gives warning

Tags: drush, database, backups

When I ran `drush sql-dump --result-file`, it came back with a warning and a success message.

```
system(): Cannot execute a blank command exec.inc:36                 [warning]
Database dump saved to                                               [success]
/my/homedir/drush-backups/unknown/20150113014628/_20150113_014628.sql
```

However, I checked inside the directory and no `.sql` backup file can be found. I have also read [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1453044), but I am not using drush aliases.

How can I fix this and backup my database using the command line?

Comment: try running the same drush command with `--debug` to see more detailed system issues you may be experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But my colleague has figured it out now.

Answer (score 2):

I was following the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/backing-your-site-command-line), which told me to execute the command in my 'From your Drupal directory', so I executed the command on my Drupal installation root directory.

I have a multi-site set up, and running it inside my site directory `/sites/mysite/` worked.